# error C2512: 'Box' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++

I'm still new to C++ and I can't seem to find the exact answer elsewhere. I am trying to initialize a Box object that requires 2 floats in the constructor. Box is derived from Game Object.

I tried Box *box = new Box(20,20);

```
    class GameObject {
        public: 
            GameObject::GameObject(float Posx, float Posy) {
                posx = Posx;
                posy = Posy;
            };
        protected: //Positions
            float posx;
            float posy;

            virtual void setPosition(float x, float y) { posx = x; posy = y;};

        };


        class Box : GameObject { // Box is Derived from GameObject
        public:

            float sizex;
            float sizey;

            void setSize(float x, float y) {sizex = x; sizey = y;};

        };
```

Comment: Show us a complete program, or at *least* where the error actually occurs. [http://sscce.org](http://sscce.org).

Comment: And there is no need of `GameObject::` while defining functions inside the class body. It would rather give you error.

Comment: Welcome then to the most *horrible* language. I'm wondering why so much programmers (me too!) are in-love with it.

Comment: One suggestion: use [initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/init-lists.html).

Comment: Note that `Box` inherits _privately_ from `GameObject`, there is a really high chance that you meant `class Box : public GameObject` instead...

Comment: Im coming from Java so the different inheritence is confusing me

Comment: @Tikitaco: Please don't try to write _Java_ code in _C++_, you will do all sort of things wrong....

Comment: I'm not trying to write Java code. I'm trying to write C++ code ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `GameObject` requires a position to be initialized, you simply cannot create a `GameObject` without that information. A `Box` is *implemented-in-terms-of* a `GameObject`, so a `Box` needs to be initialized with a position as well.

You need to create a constructor for `Box` that will take care of initializing its `GameObject` position. Like this:

```
class Box : GameObject {
public:
    Box(float Posx, float Posy) : GameObject( Posx, Posy ) {}

    /*...*/
};
```

And presumably you will need a way to construct a `Box` out of a position *and* a size:

```
class Box : GameObject {
public:
    Box(float Posx, float Posy, float Sizex, float Sizey)
      : GameObject( Posx, Posy )
      , sizex( Sizex ), sizey( Sizey )
    {}

    /*...*/
};
```

Finally, you could also add a constructor for `Box` that says that a *default constructed* `Box` starts at position `0,0` and has no size:

```
class Box : GameObject {
public:
    Box() : GameObject( 0, 0 ), sizex( 0 ), sizey( 0 ) {}

    /*...*/
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As I'm writing this, the posted code is as follows:

```
class GameObject {


public: 
    GameObject::GameObject(float Posx, float Posy) {
        posx = Posx;
        posy = Posy;
    };
protected:
    float posx;
    float posy;

    virtual void setPosition(float x, float y) { posx = x; posy = y;};

};


class Box : GameObject {
public:

    float sizex;
    float sizey;

    void setSize(float x, float y) {sizex = x; sizey = y;};

};
```

That won't compile because class  `GameObject` has no default constructor that the generated default constructor for class `Box` can use.

One fix is to define a constructor for class `Box`.

---

While you're at it, you probably want to use `public` inheritance.

For `class` inheritance is `private` by default (it's opposite for `struct`).

Wherever you find yourself using `private` inheritance, consider containment instead.

---

Also, since e.g. the literal `3.14` is a `double`, not a `float`, it's generally a good idea to use `double` instead of `float`.

It can be faster.

And it's certainly less awkward.